# git - difference between worktrees and shared repositories?

Tags: git

What is the difference between the git worktree command and sharing a repository locally by cloning it multiple times with the --shared switch?

My objective is to clone a relatively large repository to the disk of developers' machines once only and use that one repository for development on multiple branches. We cannot use git worktree because we use Eclipse  and [Eclipse does not support worktrees at the moment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=477475).

What I've tried and what seems to work is the following:

1. Clone the repository once from GitLab: `git clone ssh://host/repo.git repository-master`
2. Clone it again without checking out anything as a shared repository. This just creates some reference files to the pack files in the first repository, not wasting any disk space:
   `git clone --shared repository-master/ repository-branch1/`
3. Add the GitLab repository as a remote to the shared repository repository-branch1: `git remote add gitlab ssh://host/repo.git`
4. Fetch the data `git fetch`
5. Check out the desired branch into a new local branch in the second clone repository-branch1: `git checkout -b branch1 gitlab/branch1`

This seems to solve all problems:

1. There are multiple branches checked out at the same time.
2. You can push commits to both branches.
3. You can import projects into Eclipse and Eclipse will recognize the repository.
4. There is only one cloned repository on the disk.

Am I missing something here? Surely, there must be a reason to use  the worktree command over this other than convenience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clone that uses `--shared` (or the implied `--shared` from some pathname-based clones) is a separate repository.  By using hard links<sup>1</sup> (which must be supported by your operating system), you get all the goodness of saving disk space,<sup>2</sup> with total safety because Git never overwrites any existing data, it only adds new data or, in relatively rare cases, unlinks the file, which is now harmless since that just decreases the number of Git repositories using the file.

A *work-tree*, made with `git worktree add`, is *not* a separate repository.  Everything you do *in* that work-tree, to any branch or tag that you're *not* on in that work-tree, is immediately seen by all the other work-trees that share the repository.  The work-tree has its own `HEAD` (usually attached to a branch name but optionally detached), its own index, and of course its own work-tree.  Nearly everything else is shared (there's a few other magically-private references, such as for `git bisect`, but any stashes, for instance, are shared across work-trees).

Your existing process is fine; just note that the disk-space-sharing will eventually degrade as described in footnote 2.

---

<sup>1</sup>Making a hard link to some underlying file object adds a new name, and increments the link count.  The link count always represents the number of *names* for the file.  The unlink operation described above is a name-deletion, rather than a file-deletion; the file itself goes away only when the last reference goes away.

<sup>2</sup>This savings sort of degrades over time.  The two separate repositories initially share all the underlying storage, but then at some point, one repository decides to pack loose objects, or repack an existing pack, breaking some the links.  The other repository now has, in essence, its own private copy.  Eventually, all the links may have been severed, so that each repository is truly independent.  The repositories continue to work but there is no space-savings any more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're missing anything. Your workflow is perfect for the scenario you are describing. I see worktrees as quick-fix folders that I expect to discard soon, or for two branches I'm going to work on for a while by myself, but the shared clone works just as well for either.

Your workflow allows multiple developers to share the packed files when working on the same machine. Where a worktree would do better is once you've been working for a while with your shared repositories, new commits will likely not be shared, but rather be downloaded into each individual sandbox. On the other hand, I don't see worktrees being a good idea for sharing between different developers, but they would guarantee just one downloaded copy of the git repo for all the worktrees linked together.

The only downside I see from your setup is that it takes longer to create. But once created, it is a good solution.

Actually, there is another consideration, which probably does not apply to you, but is worth mentioning: under some circumstances, `git clone --shared` will not actually share the files, e.g., if you're crossing file-system or mounting point boundaries. I've had it fail to properly share for me before. But if your clones are truly shared, and they will almost certainly be given the way your create them, you won't have this problem.